# I am having a problem using rsync

Tags: ubuntu, backup

How do I backup all the files on my Ubuntu machine using `rsync` on a SystemRescueCd? I tried:

```
rsync -avHPx /home/AMP /home/mydir/data
```

But got:

> rsync: link_stat "/home/AMP" failed: No such file or directory (2)
>   sent 12 bytes  received 12 bytes  48.00 bytes/sec
>   total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
>   rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors)

Comment: The problem is a tiny mistake irrelevant to the question, merely the fact that the partition wasn't mounted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is what are you backing up to?  Typically this will be an external disk or storage on another server.  The answer

```
rsync -aHPx /source /dest
```

given above is correct.  In your case /source will just be /.

suppose you are backing up to a USB disk which appears as block device /dev/sdb.  The exact commands to back up your system would be (run as root):

```
mount /dev/sdb /mnt
rsync -aHPx / /mnt
```

(The -x prevents you from backing up /mnt to /mnt as this tells rsync not to cross filesystem boundaries.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it working before you answer. Ya i did not do mount.

Answer (score 1):

Type as root:

```
rsync -avHPx /source /dest
```

Comment: See question edit

Comment: mount your partition first.